# Allow sites to access your camera and microphone in Chrome/Firefox separately

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, camera, microphone

Assume one client wants to enable camera only and another client wants to enable microphone only.

How to set in Chrome / Firefox?

Answer (score 5):

**Firefox version >46.0 setting:**

Right Click at the page you want > View Page Info > Permission (tab) > Use the Microphone -> Allow.

Comment: What about latest verion of firefox ( 68.0 (32-bit) )??? can anyone help..

Comment: For Linux Firefox 68.0 64-bit, is also the same setting.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, type *about:permissions* in the location/address bar to access the Permissions Manager, where you can set global as well as per-website permissions for several actions and devices including camera and microphone - See [this support article](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/permissions-manager-give-ability-store-passwords-set-cookies-more).

I wouldn't know how to do so for Chrome.

Comment: `about:permissions` is not working on firefox 46.0.1

Comment: Dear Tonnes, as your answer doesn't work anymore (as it used to), maybe it's time to remove it because it might mislead other users.