# Enable disable Camera settings in Firefox/Safari

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari

I am working on a product that uses the camera access from the browser. I need to create a help page for users so that if there is an issue they can check the browser camera settings.

Chrome browser has a very nice page for enabling and disabling camera access permissions for a website.
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?hl=en

Was wondering if there are similar pages for other browsers mainly Firefox or safari?

Comment: Safari does not support WebRTC/getUserMedia, FYI...

Comment: Thanks Rob, I figured it out. What about FF?

Comment: For Firefox, you might find the answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545084/allow-sites-to-access-your-camera-and-microphone-in-chrome-firefox-separately